# How to make Sure Keyboard is not placed over an Entry when it is focused in Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an `Entry` which is placed in a `ContentView`, and this `ContentView` is placed in a Grid. When this `Entry` is Focused, the Keyboard is placed over the `ContentView` preventing the user from seeing the Entry.

I would like to know if there is a way to determine if a View is Visible and if not make sure it is (prevent the Keyboard from being placed over it).

Any thoughts on how I could do this.

I would need this to work on iOS specifically, Android and Windows seem not to have this issue in my use-case.

Comment: Place the view inside of a `ScrollView` and it will handle moving the entry upwards

Comment: Android offers a a way to do it, [Soft Keyboard Input mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode) moves everything upwards in order to show the Entry and the Keyboard

Comment: So it works on Android and UWP automatically when inside a Scrollview but not on iOS. Is there something specific I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android platform, the official document provides Soft Keyboard Input Mode. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode for details.

On IOS platform, you can query KeyboardOverlap installation in IOS's nuget, and then add `KeyboardOverlapRenderer.Init ();` in AppDelegate to achieve the effect in IOS.

Comment: Partially, solves it one use case but didn't solve it in another. I think its safe to say it works though. so I will mark this as an answer.